# Most applicaions will not start

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, system-apps

I am having a very odd problem, I first noticed it with the Camera App, but it also happens with the Facebook App,  News App,  Skype, OneDrive, Sport.   (But IE, Phone, SMS, Store seems to be OK)

When I click on one of these apps on the start screen, the display goes block, then the start screan is shown again.

I have done a soft reset (hold down the volume down and power buttons, turn off, then turn on.) and it does not change anything.

Microsoft Lumia 535
OS Version 8.10.14234.375

**Sorry about the bad tagging, but I can't work out the tag to use.**